# How to name boolean variable that indicates whether to do something?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

As far I as my experience tells me, boolean variables usually named in format - `is/has`+`noun/adj/verb`, e.g `isValid`, `isButton`, `hasClickedLink`

But say there is the case where we have some flag which straightly tells whether to do something, like for example, `clean` to indicate that cleanup function should be automatically called in the end.

How to name such a booleans? Same `clean` - is ambiguous, looks like a method name more, but naming it `toClean` is, I don't know, too weird. Or should I name it like `callCleanup`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `toClean` does not seem very weird, or maybe more specific `isCleanReqd`. This entertains opinion-based answers/comments, which unfortunately is off-topic as per SO.

Comment: Consider `should` as in `shouldClean`

Comment: How about: `if (notClean) then { Clean(dirtyWashing); }`

Comment: `if dirty then clean()`

Answer (score 1):

In this case i usually append the word *wanted*, which makes *cleanWanted*. In general, for boolean variables I also prefer to always let the last word be an adjective. This makes it very clear that it represents a truth value. The is/has prefix is often superfluous, as in *hasClickedLink* which is more concisely communicated with *linkClicked*.

Answer (score 0):

methods are usually one word adjectives with a capitol at the start

maybe create a method that sets the flag
for example

```
void Clean(){
    clean = True;
}
```